# if <li> contains text .addClass

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm trying to add a class to my `<li>` whenever it contains "Tienes" (it means "you have" in Spanish"). I'm using this:

```
$('.pm-text:contains("Tienes")').parent().addClass('new-pm');
```

but with no results. Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

This is the HTML I'm using:

```
<li id="menu-item-458" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-458 erqf">
    <a href="/privmsg?folder=inbox" class="pm-text"> TEXT HERE </a>
</li>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kkzyd/ --- your code does work.

Comment: The problem I had was because of the plataform I was using.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are trying to access the elements even before it existed.

Put it inside DOM ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pm-text:contains("Tienes")').parent().addClass('new-pm');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually was the problem. And i should probably starting looking for tutorials.

Comment: glad to have helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// here
});
```

Comment: Is it an answer or a question?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Joce i'm sorry, I have edited it now